# How to strip string in .htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have URL:

http://www.mydomain.com/326-something/something.jpg

This follows to:
http://www.mydomain.com/img/p/3/2/6/something.jpg

But I have also URL:
http://www.mydomain.com/125-326-something/something.jpg

How can I ignore this 125- ? Of course I have urls with prefixes like 126, 127 etc. How can I ignore this in .htaccess?

I want to display http://www.mydomain.com/img/p/3/2/6/something.jpg from this url http://www.mydomain.com/125-326-something/something.jpg

Here is my htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
```

Comment: I hope this is a personal project or the next person who is going to have you job later is going to hate the previous developer :P

Comment: It's open source software and I want to have retro-compatibility with previous version of images url because 

now URLs are:
http://www.mydomain.com/326-something/something.jpg

Previous urls are:
http://www.mydomain.com/125-326-something/something.jpg

I want to display images from old urls with new format.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you ever considered a PHP rewriter instead to make it a tiny bit less... ugly?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not a author of that, it's from PrestaShop ;) I do not have time to rewrite whole dispatching process in this system :)

Comment: ok now I feel sorry for you instead of the next developer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would *highly* recommend routing all requests through a controlling PHP script and managing this in a real programming language instead of mod_rewrite.

But to answer the question directly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^\d+-(\d+-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*/.+?\.jpg)$ $1
```

Add these lines (untested) before the above rules, and it should strip off the part you don't want before allowing it to fall through the regular rewrite process.

Comment: Unfortunately, the developers from prestashop.com invented that approach ... Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly.

Comment: @KrystianPodemski Where your example URL says `something` is that always the same text repeated twice? If so this can be made a little more robust with a back reference, if not then there is a hole in this (that I can't see any way to plug) in that if the text portion begins with numerics and a dash, they will get stripped as well. If this can never happen then there's no need to worry about it.

Comment: Yep, that is always type of image, in that case it's "large". URL has always the same structure and that solution from you it's perfect for all of my old images url.